# Do observers agree on forces in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, forces, classical-mechanics, inertial-frames, observers

If $\vec p$ is the spatial part of the four-momentum $p^{\mu} = m\gamma(c, \vec v)$, then in special relativity forces are defined such that
$$\vec F = \frac{\textrm{d}\vec p}{\textrm{d}t},$$
where $t$ is the time measured in the system of reference where we are measuring $\vec v$ and $\vec F$ in.

Will two inertial observers agree on $\vec F$?

Comment: No, they will not; the result is trivial from the fact that force is at least a vector, and there are no invariant vectors in the theory. Invariant quantities are scalars. You can derive the force transformation laws, but it would not see much use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

The three-acceleration scales as $\gamma^{3}$ i.e. if your (proper) acceleration is $a$ and I observe your (three) acceleration to be $a'$ then I observe
$$ a' = \frac{a}{\gamma^3}.$$
Hence the (three-)force I would observe is
$$ F' = \gamma m \frac{a}{\gamma^3} = \frac{ma}{\gamma^2} = \frac{F}{\gamma^2}.$$

You can define a [four-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-force) as the rate of change of the four-momentum, and as you would expect the norm of the four-force is a scalar invariant.

Comment: This isn't quite right -- you seem to be assuming $F = ma$, which in relativity is different from $F = dp/dt$. The second expression is the standard definition of three-force, and it gives $F_x = F'_x$ but $F_y = F_y' / \gamma$, i.e. only transverse forces redshift.